# tlmgr update --self fails with a weird error message (Windows 10)

Tags: tlmgr

I have `TL2018` on windows 10. When trying to update packages with `tlmgr`, it said that `tlmgr` itself needs to be updated.

However, the command `tlmgr update --self` failed for me with the following error message

```
λ tlmgr update --all --self
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr.pl: Preparing TeX Live infrastructure update...
DO NOT CLOSE THIS WINDOW!
TeX Live infrastructure update in progress ...
Detailed command logging to "\\icnas1.cc.ic.ac.uk\kg314\texlive\2018\temp\update-self.log"
Could not change working directory to "\\icnas1.cc.ic.ac.uk\kg314\texlive\2018\temp\.."
Aborting infrastructure update, no changes have been made.
```

How to fix this issue? I am unable to install any packages too in this current state.

#### Update

I tried to do a fresh installation of `texlive` on the machine. However, after reaching the `tar` package, the installation crashes abruptly with the following entry appearing last in the log.

```
TLUtils::untar: H:\install-tl-20190207\tlpkg\installer\tar.exe xmf C:\Users\kg314\AppData\Local\Temp\goATAeqfOX\xskZVdlZXH/kpathsea.win32.tar failed (in H:/texlive/2018)
TLPDB::_install_package: untar failed
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
Or you can restart by running the installer with:
  install-tl-windows.bat --profile installation.profile [EXTRA-ARGS]
or
  install-tl-advanced.bat --profile installation.profile [EXTRA-ARGS]
```

Now, I am in an inconsistent state.  Any further `tlmgr update --all` simply results in an error

`tlmgr.pl: Fundamental package texlive.infra not present, uh oh, goodbyeShould not happen, texlive.infra not found at \\icnas1.cc.ic.ac.uk\kg314\texlive\2018\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl line 7344`

Comment: Have you been able to update before? I'm a little weary about your use of unc paths (\\....), they might not work. But if you have been able to update before...

Comment: @daleif yes, totally was able to update before ever since TL2018 was released. Something bad happened just today (07/Feb/2019). Even a fresh install fails complaining that `untar` failed, and that too just for a minimal install

Comment: Hmm, no clue then (I don't use Windows). Just for the heck of it: have you tried a different mirror? You mention untar errors, could you cite those?

Comment: @daleif Yes. Problems with all mirrors. Have updated the question with `untar` errors.

Comment: Download `http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.exe` and run it to update tlmgr (texlive should be in the path, the application uses kpsewhich to find out where to put the files).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ok, that worked; waiting for `tlmgr update --all` for package updates.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Nope...`tlmgr.pl: Fundamental package tlperl.win32 not present, uh oh, goodbyeShould not happen, tlperl.win32 not found at ...`

Comment: Well I have no idea in what state your system is after your reinstallation tries. I got an error from tlmgr and followed the disaster recovery instructions https://tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html and it worked.  But you should better ask on the texlive list. There are the people who know the system.

Comment: at first glance it looks like you have multiple network paths to the same shared location since \\icnas1.cc.ic.ac.uk\kg314\texlive\2018 looks like it should be  H:/texlive/2018 this type of issue will happen to me when not correctly logged in to a sharepoint server where my S:\ is mapped to a \\Server\UserDirectory It would help if you could explain the type of installer and relative network locations you are trying to work with First question is that IF H: is on a server (which may not always be accessible) where are you wanting TeX Live to run from and for how many users?

Comment: The H: drive and the long network name are one and the same

Comment: For a HOST of reasons such as you are experiencing I now tend to work as local as possible (usually portable) All to often a server source repository is unable to allow (IT capping?) some installers to run. I know others have installed OK but possibly in a more relaxed system environment. So I have learnt some of my frequent installation files will repeatedly fail unless brought onto the local drive, it is a bug bear to wait for large downloads to C:\drive\install (or whatever) but I know it will save repeating grief over and over. Consider where both installer and target files are best placed